# Separar os hits de acesso por área no Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics-api

Possuo um sistema de gestão empresarial que estou usando o Google Analytics para rastrear as áreas mais acessadas, porem junto a este sistema está o site de apresentação e alguns hotsites.

Como desenvolvi em PHP usando uma framework, cada área (site/sistema/hotsite) possui um layout próprio onde coloco o código do Google Analytics.

Gostaria de fazer uma categorização mais ou menos da seguinte maneira:

```
Área: Site
/sobre
/quem-somos
/planos-precos
/funcionalidades
/blog

Área: Sistema
/login
/contatos
/contatos/visualizacao
/administrativo
/administrativo/cargos
/financeiro
/financeiro/movimentacoes
/financeiro/fluxo-de-caixa
```

Isso facilitará a analise dos dados muito.

Sei que é possível criar eventos, mas até onde entendi, creio que seja para recursos onde não é capturado a ação do usuário, como por exemplo um clique em uma âncora, ampliar uma imagem, etc. Não sei se dá para associar um evento ao hit logo que a página é carregada.

Comment: Você quer disparar o evento ao entrar na página/Layout for carregado?

Comment: Isso. Para cada página é gerado um hit só por carregar a API do analytics, eu estava querendo categorizar este hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, isso pode ser resolvido na ferramenta criando uma nova visualização e separando os acessos de determinados subdiretórios.

Crie duas views, uma pro sistema e uma pro site, e use os filtros para incluir apenas acessos das páginas que você quiser, assim você terá dois relatórios separados, um para cada área do site.

Mandar um evento para identificar o tipo de página junto com o hit é redundante e vai afetar seu bounce rate.

Valeu

Answer (score 0):

- Vá em Administrador;
- Selecione o select de propriedade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Criar nova propriedade;
- Preencha os campos, será gerado um novo número UA-xxxx;
- Aplique na sua aplicação.